# Semaphore in Swift not working for Firebase Authentication

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to achieve functionality similar to Javascript/C#'s async/await. I am trying out the use of semaphores, and found that it works with URLSession in my XCode Playground.

Thus, i am now trying to perform the same thing with Firebase Authentication using the following code:

```
var response:String? = "test"
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, err) in

    if err != nil {
        response = "\(String(describing: err))"
    }else{
        response = nil
    }
    semaphore.signal()
}
let _ = semaphore.wait()
if response == nil{
    self.transitionToHome()
}
```

However, the simulator freezes forever, appearing as if the `semaphore.signal()` never got called. Placing print statements near the `semaphore.signal()` didn't appear as well. I've also placed the firestore code in a `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async` and subsequently tried to retrieve the response value in  `DispatchQueue.main.async` but the response did not get updated as well. The code below reflects what i did:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, err) in
        if err != nil {
            response = "\(String(describing: err))"
        }else{
            response = nil
        }
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    let _ = semaphore.wait()
}

if response == nil{
    self.transitionToHome()
}
```

While this did not freeze up the UI, the response value was not picked up after the `DispatchQueue` was called. I've also called the `if-else` block within a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block but that had the same result too.

Further, after waiting for a period of time, i see this error popping up in my xcode terminal:

```
020-01-02 01:33:25.447842+0800 das-carddeckapp[78136:10508853] Connection 4: received failure notification
2020-01-02 01:33:25.448179+0800 das-carddeckapp[78136:10508853] Connection 4: failed to connect 1:50, reason -1
2020-01-02 01:33:25.448387+0800 das-carddeckapp[78136:10508853] Connection 4: encountered error(1:50)
2020-01-02 01:33:25.457587+0800 das-carddeckapp[78136:10508853] Task <3A3720D6-7549-4C31-96A2-C88B89294821>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1009 [1:50])
```

I know that using completion handlers will make this work, but I want to try to get this to work before resorting to completion handlers. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: change this line  let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0) to 
 let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

Comment: @Rob i've edited my question to reflect this. I know that semaphores is considered a bad pattern but i just wanted to understand why is it not working. And from your first comment, what do you mean by that exactly in terms of code? Thanks a lot though!!

Comment: @jawadAli, unfortunately, that did not work, and although the UI did not freeze i was unable to retrieve the correct value of the response variable.

Answer (score 1):

The first example (where you’re calling `wait` on the main thread) is “deadlocking” because it is blocking the main thread with `wait`, which is to be signaled from the `createUser` closure, which also wants to run on the main thread (which you’ve blocked).

> I know that semaphores is considered a bad pattern but i just wanted to understand why is it not working.

Your second example, where you are dispatching the `wait` to the global queue resolves the deadlock. But because you’ve dispatched that asynchronously, that means that the main thread will carry on as the global queue waits for the response. As a result, you are almost guaranteed to not have a value ready to return. (And if you attempt to change this to call the global queue synchronously, you’d just re-introduce the deadlock.)

In short, you can’t easily have the main queue wait for an asynchronous method which calls its completion handler on the main queue. That is a programmatic “Catch-22”.

But setting that aside, if this is an iOS app, it just simply a serious problem to ever block the main thread (even if you could solve the deadlock). It’s a horrible UX when an app freezes. This is especially true for unfortunate mobile users who find themselves on poor cellular connection, where it might result in a non-trivial delay. Worse, if you’re unlucky enough to block the main thread at the wrong time, the iOS watchdog process may unceremoniously kill your app.

Hey, I get it. We’ve all been there. When we first encountered asynchronous programming patterns, like network requests, it feels it would be *so* much more logical and intuitive if we could just wait for the response. But it should be avoided at all costs. You’ll be much happier in the long run if you stick with well-established asynchronous programming patterns, rather than fighting it.